# How do I create a Namecoin address?

Tags: address, namecoin

My mining pool has merged with Namecoin, and I need a Namecoin address. How do I create one ? Do I need to install another client ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either install a client, or use some Namecoin-Bitcoin exchange (like [BTC-E](https://btc-e.com)) to obtain an address. It`s generally the same as getting a Bitcoin address really, only a bit less popular.

Comment: I think I had read that BitParking deposit addresses were single-use, and not for repeated mining payouts.

Comment: @StephenGornick I'm not really sure if it's a rule or a suggestion. I guess I'll change my answer regardless. Thanks for pointing it out, I don`t really use the service too much.

Comment: where can I get namecoin client?

Answer (score 1):

If you know Python, then there is a library called Coinkit that you can use to create Namecoin addresses:

https://github.com/halfmoonlabs/coinkit

It has step by step instructions as well, but you'll do something like

`pip install coinkit`

once installed, open python and:

`from coinkit.keypair import NamecoinKeypair`

create a new private-key and NMC-address pair:

`keypair = NamecoinKeypair()`

You can get the private key by:

`keypair.private_key()`

And the corresponding namecoin address as:

`keypair.address()`